# HANA xsodata create using procedure

Tags: odata, procedure, hana, hana-xs

Trying to create xsodata via dbprocedure

```
"X"."SHOPLIST/Header" as "Header"
navigates ("ToItem" as "ItemRef")
create using "X"."SHOPLIST.shoplist::create";
```

it says Syntax error at line: 3, column: 15.

```
create using "SHOPLIST.shoplist::create";
```

it says Unknown object "SHOPLIST.shoplist::create".

Procedure name is "X"."SHOPLIST.shoplist::create" (it works ok in console).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that xsodata doesn't work with DB artifacts. I had to create .hdbprocedure and then it would accept it without schema prefix...